# Mysql matching getting users with either similiar interest or same gender for each user

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get three matched users for each user in 'users' table based on same 'interestid' from table 'userinterest' on priority and if the user has no interest then if his 'gender' matches with other users then get userid of three of those users.

User table has userid and gender while userinterest table has two columns u_id and interest_id WHERE u_id is userid.

Each user might have multiple interests but even if one interest matches we can take that user.

The type of result i am looking for is two column one with userid we are getting result for and other column with group concatenated three user ids.

```
 12 | 32,34,23  
 13 | 33,35,23  
 14 | 22,35,37
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Try not to confuse issues of data retrieval (the mysql part) with issues of data display (the php part)

Answer (score 2):

You can use an aggregation query to get the number of interests that two users have in common:

```
select ui.user, ui2.user as otherUsaer, count(*) as numInterests
from userinterest ui join
     userinterest ui2
     on ui.interest = ui2.interest and ui.user <> ui2.user
group by ui.user, ui2.user;
```

You can then re-aggregate this to get the three most common users for each user:

```
select user, substring_index(group_concat(otherUser order by numInterests desc), ',', 3) as top3
from (select ui.user, ui2.user as otherUsaer, count(*) as numInterests
      from userinterest ui join
           userinterest ui2
           on ui.interest = ui2.interest and ui.user <> ui2.user
      group by ui.user, ui2.user
     ) uu
group by user;
```

This assumes that you do not have too many users; otherwise, the intermediate string buffer used for `substring_concat()` will overflow.  (The default buffer length can be expanded.)  An alternative using variables is just harder to code.

I would also recommend that you avoid thinking about gender.  If it is really an interest, then add it to the interests table.  But, here is one way you can include gender:

```
select user, substring_index(group_concat(otherUser order by numInterests desc), ',', 3) as top3
from (select ui.user, ui2.user as otherUsaer,
             (count(*) + (u.gender = u2.gender)) as numInterests
      from userinterest ui join
           userinterest ui2
           on ui.interest = ui2.interest and ui.user <> ui2.user join
           user u
           on ui.user = u.user join
           user u2
           on ui2.user = u2.user
      group by ui.user, ui2.user
     ) uu
group by user;
```

Comment: First of all Thanks alot for help! Actually i tried my way but the problem is that it very slow and causes load on sql. Just to mention that I do not want the most common users; just even if one interest matches i can take that user. Sorry to disturb you but is there anyway i can make it faster? concerning if i do not look for most common user but just one interest match and add?

Comment: One more thing please if you can help me with. Your query is working well for me. Just if I do not need group concatenation for matches then how this query will change. Please help.

Comment: @user3881111 . . . Just run the subquery.